# RNFirebaseNotifications.h not found after migrating to firebase v6. React Native

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am migrating to a new version of RN and firebase as well . I did everything as it is written in migration guideline of firebase v6 but now, xcode shows me error **'RNFirebaseNotifications.h' file not found** and **RNFirebaseMessaging.h file not found**. Since RN > 0.60 uses auto linking, can it be the reason that xcode cannot find required modules ? 
If you know how to solve the issue, please, let me know. 
My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.7.1",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.0.1",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.2.0",
"@tinkoff/utils": "^1.0.2",
"buffer": "^5.2.1",
"connected-react-navigation": "^0.0.4",
"formik": "^1.5.2",
"jetifier": "^1.6.4",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
}
```

Unfortunately, I've not found any solution on firebase github page :(

Comment: how you fixed it ?

Comment: @CodeWriter Hi, nope, i've not managed to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It passed a long time from the first time I asked the question, anyway, starting from v6 firebase implemented all required stuff regarding messaging by their own, so started from v6 a developers don't need to manually add RNFirebaseMessaging import to AppDelegate. If you face the same error just remove all occurrences of RNFirebaseMessaging from the file. take a look [here](https://rnfirebase.io/migrating-to-v6#cloud-messaging)

Answer (score -3):

Try `@import Firebase;` in the file showing the error:

```
RNFirebaseMessaging.h file not found
```